# How to input a list (of indices) into ndarray to access an element?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

I have a high-dimensional ndarray that looks like below, and I'm trying to access one element with a list of N indices:

```
>>> grid = np.ones([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> ids = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> print(grid[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
1
>>> print(grid[*id])

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(grid[*id])
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried `print(grid[id])`, but that prints out the entire `grid` instead of one element.

What's the correct syntax to do this, and how come starred expression doesn't work in this case?

Comment: The---arguably not very pretty---way to make the star expression work is `grid[(*ids,)]`.

Comment: `grid[id]` actually produces a (6,3,3,3,3,3) array, with 6 copies of `grid[0,...]` (the first 'row' of `grid`.  A list `ids` indexes the first dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy doesn't duck-type correctly here.  It has to be a tuple.

```
grid[tuple(ids)]
```

Comment: It's Python itself that doesn't allow the * expansion in an indexing expression.

Comment: Obviously, since that's a `SyntaxError` :)   .. this was more referring to `grid[ids]`, which OP presumably tried first and found to be not working ..

Comment: *facepalm* yup, that works.